# Why output is true and false?

Tags: java

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        Integer a = 10;
        Integer b =10;
        Integer c = 145;
        Integer d = 145;
        System.out.println(a==b);
        System.out.println(c==d);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been around since 2004 when Java 5.0 was introduced. You might expect this has been answered before ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - answered several times by several different people.. :P

Answer (score 5):

Integer class keeps a local cache for values between `-128` and `127`.. and returns the same object.

```
    Integer a = 10;
    Integer b =10;
    Integer c = 145;
    Integer d = 145;
    System.out.println(a==b); // so, a and b are references to the same object --> prints true
    System.out.println(c==d);// so, c and d are references to different objects --> returns false
}
```

Comment: Side note: It's possible to alter the size of this cache using the `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<size>` argument on the HotSpot VM, so it's entirely possible that `c == d` could return `true`.